# What library contains cdefs.h on Alpine?

Tags: docker, gcc, alpine-linux

I am trying to compile some code on a Docker image running Alpine. However, gcc keeps terminating due to `fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory`. People on Google were saying to do

`apt install libc6-dev-i386 gcc-multilib`

Which I translated to `apk add libc6-dev-i386 gcc-multilib`. However, then I just get the error. `ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:` for both of the libraries.

My Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM alpine

ADD . .
RUN apk update && apk add gcc make openssl libressl-dev musl-dev && make

ENTRYPOINT ./restrictions-crack "$hash" "$salt"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up finding it, the library is `bsd-compat-headers`

Answer (score -1):

You might use `build-base` - this is a meta-package that will install the GCC, libc-dev and binutils packages (amongst others).

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine

ADD . .
RUN apk update && apk add build-base && make

ENTRYPOINT ./restrictions-crack "$hash" "$salt"
```

Comment: Same issue sadly

Comment: I've reproduced your issue, but with what I posted above it worked :( Maybe try separating `RUN`'s, like one command per one `RUN`. Maybe there's something with jobs concatenating and `add` is running in parallel with `update` in this case, which will obviously produce the exact problem.

Comment: I’m not sure why it’s so mad. The code I’m working with is at https://github.com/alex-taffe/iOS-Restrictions-Cracker (in the v2 branch). @trust512

Comment: There must be something with your environment, I can easily build and execute the repo you provided. Try `docker system prune`, get your docker to a stable version - mine is `Docker version 18.03.1-ce`, remove the old image via `docker rmi restrictions` - if it fails then remove the containers too and retry.

Comment: I'm on the same version `Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40`. I modified my Dockerfile to look like this:

`RUN apk update && apk add gcc make openssl libressl-dev musl-dev build-base && make`

And it still fails. Your exact example fails as well due to the OpenSSL libraries, but adding just those causes a failure as well.

Comment: I found the library, it's bsd-compat-headers